# Parent and child proc sync using signals

Tags: c, synchronization, signals, parent-child

I have some troubles:
it is not clear for me how to synchronise parent and child processes using signals, and this code doesn't work.
I thought that it should work like that: parent sends signal to child, child's `pause()` is end, child sends signal to parent, parent's `pause()` is end .. etc
why it is not so?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void handler_cp() {
}

void handler_pc() {
}

void child_proc() {
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < 50; ++i) {
        pause();
        kill(getppid(), SIGUSR2);
    }

void parent_proc(pid_t ch) {
    int j = 0;
    for (; j < 50; ++j) {
        kill(ch, SIGUSR1);
        pause();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    signal(SIGUSR1, handler_cp);
    signal(SIGUSR2, handler_pc);
    pid_t ch = fork();
    if (ch == 0)
        child_proc();
    else
        parent_proc(ch);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _How_ do you know it doesn't work? Do you set a breakpoint in the signal handlers and run in a debugger?

Comment: The signal handlers should have a signature of `void handler_pc(int signum) {}` (it is formally Ok if they do nothing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signal may arrive before `pause` is called, in which case it will deadlock. Using signals for synchronization is, in general, a very bad idea.

Comment: what should i use instead of pause() there to catch a signal?

Comment: `sigprocmask` and `sigwaitinfo`. But by the time you do that you just made signals into clunky pipes.

Answer (score 1):

In the child_proc method, reverse the lines as :

```
          kill(getppid(),SIGUSR2);
          pause();
```

This will wake the parent before the child goes to sleep.